# How to install FileZilla3 on kali linux?

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, filezilla

I have an FTP server on my Windows machine, and I've been trying to install `filezilla` in order to connect to the FTP server with it. I went to the `filezilla` official website and downloaded the software for Linux 64bit.

The file which I downloaded has a `.tar.bz2` format so I extracted it using the `tar -xvf` command as follows `tar -xvf Downloads/FileZilla3.tar.bz2` and now I have a directory labeled FileZilla3 which contains three other directories that match the system files in the root directory.

[image: This is an image of the downloaded file]

This is an image of the .tar.bz2 archive I downloaded file and the other folder is the uncompressed archived folder, FileZilla 3.

Inside the FileZilla3 directory there are three more directories:

[image: image of the three further directories].

How I do I install this software from here?

Comment: Welcome to U&L. You seemed to have had some problems posting your links to images but it went a bit wrong. Take a look at your edited post and see how it works.

Comment: Related to https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/4778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install filezilla3 through `apt`:

```
apt update
apt install filezilla
```

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` should contain the following lines:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me for some reason

Comment: @mmdz see my update, please.

Comment: @mndz "_for some reason_" is useless. What errors did you get? What happened? What didn't happen?

Comment: What error message.

Comment: the problem was that i installed kali offline and i didn't have the kali repos in my sources.list